# How can I update a table data (td) with respect to another table data of a different column

Tags: php, sql

I have a table I would like to display data based on other column data on the same table. Below is my code as I am now stuck on what to do.

```
<tbody>
        
    <?php
    $select=$pdo->prepare("select * from tbl_category order by catid desc");
            
    $select->execute();
            
while($row=$select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)  ){
    
    echo'
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row->catid.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->category.'</td>
    <td>
      '.$cummunlative_debt.'
    </td>
    <td>'.$row->remitted.'</td>


    <td>
<button id='.$row->catid.'" class="btn btn-info btnremit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pay Company"></span></button>  
    
    </td>
    
    <td>
<a href="#.php?id='.$row->catid.'" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Category"></span></a>   
    
    </td>
    
    <td>
<button id='.$row->catid.' class="btn btn-danger btndelete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Delete Category"></span></button>  
    
    </td>
     </tr>
     ';
    
}          
?>        
                
 </tbody>
```

**My query**

```
$cat=$pdo->prepare("select category_name from tbl_category");
  $cat->execute();
  $row=$cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$select_debts = $pdo->prepare("select sum(total_cost) as debt from tbl_stock_in where category_name='".$row->category."' group by category_name");
$select_debts->execute();
$row=$select_debts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$cummunlative_debt=$row->debt;
```

I would also like to not hardcode the SQL like this category_name='Pinnacle'...

Below is UI
[image]

you can see that BG and Pinnacle had the same values but on my database, BG had a record of zero. I need your help pls. Thanks.

**tbl_stock_in** that column called 'table debt'
[image]

**tbl_category** where category is selected from to supoort the second SQL query.
[image]

Please i need your help!!

Comment: how does the second db query relate to the code above where the HTML table content is populated? Is that the code you intend (hope) to run when you click on a button or something?

Comment: *"... BG had a record of zero ..."*, record of zero is what? total debt equal to 0? Also: you use `$cummunlative_debt` multiple times in the loop, without us seeing you updating this value in the loop.

Comment: can you add the table schemas used here? ie: for tbl_category and tbl_stock ~ my guess is you want to join these tables

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius,  I just updated the question to include the database tables.

Comment: I see that you edited the actual sql query and have once again embedded variables directly in the sql statement rather than using placeholders! You need, by the looks of this, to join the tables using some common column ~ `category_name` and `category` look the most likely

Comment: also - the column `total_cost` in `tbl_stock_in` appears to be the calculated amount based upon `stock_in` x `stock_price` ~ there is no need to maintain this sum in the db if you already know the values in these two columns ~ simply calculate it at runtime

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, do you mean making it a single column.

Comment: no - not a single column but you technically do not need the column `total_cost` when you already have `stock_in` ( quantity ) and `stock_price` ( price ) - the total is quantity * price.. just seems like redundant data to maintain

Comment: ok, thanks. please, how do I resolve the pressing problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226130/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-ugochukwu-anajemba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at this for a little while my best guess at what you are trying to do is to unify the data from both tables to display in the HTML table.

The query can potentially be modified in such a way as to allow you to draw the data from both tables and display as you wish

```
select 
    c.catid,
    c.`category`,
    ifnull(sum( s.`stock_in` * s.`stock_price` ),0) as `debt`,
    c.`remitted`
from `tbl_category` c
    left outer join `tbl_stock_in` s on s.`category_name`=c.`category`
group by c.`category`
    order by catid desc;
```

Putting that into the context of the page I put this together as a test

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    try{
        $dbport =   3306;
        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root';
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
        $dbname =   'xxx';

        $dsn = sprintf( 'mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8mb4', $dbhost, $dbport, $dbname );
        $pdo = new PDO( $dsn, $dbuser, $dbpwd );
        
        $sql='select 
            c.catid,
            c.`category`,
            ifnull(sum( s.`stock_in` * s.`stock_price` ),0) as `debt`,
            c.`remitted`
        from `tbl_category` c
            left outer join `tbl_stock_in` s on s.`category_name`=c.`category`
        group by c.`category`
            order by catid desc;';


        $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->execute();
        
    }catch( PDOException $e ){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope='col'>ID</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Company</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Total Debt</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Total Remit</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Pay</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Edit</th>
                    <th scope='col'>delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                while( $rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
                    printf(
                        '<tr>
                            <td>%1$s</td>
                            <td>%2$s</td>
                            <td>%3$s</td>
                            <td>%4$s</td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-id="%1$s" class="btn btn-info btnremit" data-action="Pay">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pay Company"></span>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-id="%1$s" class="btn btn-info btnedit" data-action="Edit">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Category"></span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-id="%1$s" class="btn btn-danger btndelete" data-action="Delete">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Delete Category"></span>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>',
                        $rs->catid,
                        $rs->category,
                        number_format($rs->debt,2),
                        number_format($rs->remitted,2)
                    );
                }          
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following depicts a semi-styled version of the output ~ the css simply removed here for brevity.
[image: Example output]

And that based upon the following db schema and data almost as per question.

```
mysql> describe tbl_stock_in;
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                   | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| sid           | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| category_name | varchar(50)            | YES  | MUL | NULL       |                |
| product_name  | varchar(128)           | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| stock_in      | int(10) unsigned       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| stock_price   | decimal(10,2) unsigned | YES  |     | 0.00       |                |
| stocked_date  | date                   | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> describe tbl_category;
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| catid    | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category | varchar(50)            | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| debt     | decimal(10,2) unsigned | YES  |     | 0.00    |                |
| remitted | decimal(10,2) unsigned | YES  |     | 0.00    |                |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)



mysql> select * from tbl_stock_in;
+-----+---------------+------------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| sid | category_name | product_name     | stock_in | stock_price | stocked_date |
+-----+---------------+------------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
|   1 | PINNACLE      | acelofenac 100ml |       10 |      880.00 | 2020-12-17   |
|   2 | PINNACLE      | acelofenac 100ml |       65 |      920.00 | 2020-12-17   |
+-----+---------------+------------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from tbl_category;
+-------+----------+------+----------+
| catid | category | debt | remitted |
+-------+----------+------+----------+
|     1 | BG       | 0.00 |     0.00 |
|     2 | PINNACLE | 0.00 |     0.00 |
+-------+----------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, professor. Just what I needed.